# Is it possible to collect latitude and longitude data of user submitting google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, geolocation

I would like to collect the user's location (Latitude and Longitude) when a google form is submitted.  Ideally, the google sheet responses will have three columns-Timestamp, Latitude, and Longitude.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible out of the box with Google forms, but you may wish to check this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081246/geolocation-filling-forms-with-latitude-and-longitude-google-maps-api 
This is a script solution.